# Animating showing/hiding Ui Bootstrap alert in Modal window AngularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to animate an ng-hide that I use on an Ui Bootstrap alert button in a Ui Bootstrap Modal window. I want the animation to slide the alert in and out, and to fade it in and out at the same time.

The alert is showing and hiding properly, but the hiding/showing animation is not working at all, and is totally baffling me.

The show-hide code is:

```
<alert type="danger" close="hideAlert = true"
    ng-hide="hideAlert" class="ng-hide">ERROR!</alert>
```

The CSS for the animation (which is probably totally incorrect...) is:

```
.alert.ng-hide-add,
.alert.ng-hide-remove {

    -moz-transition: 0.5s linear all;
    -o-transition: 0.5s linear all;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s linear all;
    transition: 0.5s linear all;

    display: block !important;
    opacity: 1;
    max-height:50px;
}


.alert.ng-hide {
    opacity: 0;
    max-height:0px;
}
```

I've included a PLNKR here to show it in all it's infamy: http://plnkr.co/edit/rQ27FDLHapOTadPJuz6z

Please help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use the .ng-hide-add and .ng-hide-remove classes, simply specify the transition in .alert and change the properties in .alert.ng-hide:

```
.alert {
    -moz-transition: 0.5s linear all;
    -o-transition: 0.5s linear all;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s linear all;
    transition: 0.5s linear all;

    display: block !important;
    opacity: 1;
    max-height:50px;
}


.alert.ng-hide {
    opacity: 0;
    max-height:0px;
}
```

Comment: I've done an updated version with your suggestion: http://plnkr.co/edit/8g0sElHHsuyzqo5FNj57 I have left out the 'display:block !important;' line, because it seems to leave a blank space the size of the hidden alert message, which is not really wanted. Now the transition doesn't work without this, it just hides itself before any fading or shrinking happens...

Comment: The `display: block !important;` cannot be omitted, see the documentation of [ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide). However, to get rid of the unwanted space, you can just set the padding to 0 like in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WcecsElbIkzM8Dzds8A8?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks gyantasaurus. One other thing - I am using animations elsewhere in my project, and when the page loads (i am using chrome) it seems to quickly hide everything that should be hidden. I was wondering if this is linked to the display setting too?

Comment: That's because you briefly see the all the html before angularjs starts - what you need is [ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)

Comment: Cheers gyantasaurus... will have a look!